# Unexpected split() behaviour Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Python 3.5.2 (v3.5.2:4def2a2901a5, Jun 26 2016, 10:47:25)
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'Checksum\t\x85\r\n'.split()
['Checksum']
```

Where is the part after the tab?

But, these work as expected:

```
>>> 'Checksum\t\x84\r\n'.split()
['Checksum', '\x84']
>>> 'Checksum\t\x85\r\n'.split('\t')
['Checksum', '\x85\r\n']
>>> 'Checksum\t\x84\r\n'.split('\t')
['Checksum', '\x84\r\n']
```

Same results on Python 3.6.6.

Interestingly, it works fine on Python 2.7.10

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Aug 17 2018, 17:41:52)
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 10.0.0 (clang-1000.0.42)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 'Checksum\t\x85\r\n'.split()
['Checksum', '\x85']
>>> 'Checksum\t\x84\r\n'.split()
 ['Checksum', '\x84']
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`split()` with no arguments splits on whitespace. `\x85` is whitespace; it's [U+0085 NEXT LINE (NEL)](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0085/index.htm).

The Python 2 version works the way you were expecting because Python 2 `str.split` only counts ASCII whitespace. If you had used a Unicode string on Python 2, you would have seen the same behavior.

Comment: thanks for the ASCII code table reference. all what I found was bogus tables.

Answer (score 5):

because it's seen as whitespace:

```
>>> "\x85".isspace()
True
```

`str.split()` without arguments removes according to all whitespace chars, it also removes "empty fields" when splitting

So all whitespace characters have been stripped. `\x84` isn't whitespace, so it's kept:

```
>>> "\x84".isspace()
False
```